# My function doesn't work into WordPress but outside, it works - what am I missing?

Tags: functions

I used a functions into my page I created for WordPress, it's working, but the functions 're not working, doesn't showing any result. For example:

```
<?php
function tester()
{

global $pol;

$pol="ok all fine and working";
}

tester();

echo $pol;
?>
```

This function works perfectly if I use it outside WordPress, but problem is when I tried using it into the file I created, it won't work.

I don´t know what the difference I need to assure to work it in WordPress other than any other PHP file.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress template files are included via *functions*, which places the scope of those included files within those functions. That's why you have to declare it global twice. Here is an example you can try with 3 simple php files to illustrate this without using WordPress:

> main.php

```
function include_file_1(){
    include '1.php';
}
function include_file_2(){
    include '2.php';
}
include_file_1();
include_file_2();
```

> 1.php

```
function tester(){
    global $pol;
    $pol="ok all fine and working";
}
```

> 2.php

```
tester();
echo $pol;
```

If you test this out, you will see you get nothing from `echo $pol`, it's not within scope. Now edit `2.php` to declare `global $pol` first:

```
global $pol
tester();
echo $pol;
```

And now you get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

It's a PHP question. That's because you do not use correct way to retrieve your global. Use the magic var_dump instead:

```
global $pols;
var_dump($pol);
```

You could also use :

```
$GLOBALS['$pol']
```

And then :

```
echo tester();
```

Comment: No work me i try these two methods and no works , and i don´t understand , because this simple function works fine when i put in single file of pfp and run , perfect works but if use into wordpress into template code no works and it´s the same php and the same server

Answer (score 0):

To use a global you need to declare it global before defining it and then pull it into [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) with `global $var_name` before using it. You did not do that. You only did half of it.

```
function tester()
{
    global $pol;

    $pol="ok all fine and working";
}
tester();

global $pol;
echo $pol;
```

But why are you using a global at all? Why not just return the value? Your code will be shorter and neater.

```
function tester()
{
    return "ok all fine and working";
}
echo tester();
```

Comment: No use return because some functions give string value and i need get this value out functions for example , number files in folder , function generate $number_files="" and i need this value from function but out the function and it´s only this

Comment: The value you get from this function-- the value of `$pol`-- will be the same whether you set a `global` or `return` a value.

Comment: But why i need repit in wordpress the variable global $poll 2 time into function and outside function no sense , in php and in all my script only put one time into function and works perfect , why no works in wordpress this

Comment: There is nothing _WordPress_ about this. It is all basic PHP. it is hard to understand you but it is clear that you misunderstand variable scope.

Comment: I use this functions in many website and no use wordpress and in all websites never need declarate 2 times the same global variable inside of function and outside , in the test function with put inside global $pol; no need put outside in my website but wordpress when i use no return never the value , i know pure php and nothing more , by this i don´t understand why no works inside wordpress using as normal php function but yes works out of worspress , sorry if you don´t understand well , i try explain the best

Comment: @s_ha_dum the bottom example wont work for me in wordpress either...any ideas why? I am also including a php file with the function in it before trying to output it. Maybe that is why?