# Fatal error Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Tags: customization, query

I am running Custom Query on `functions.php`:

```
function subscribers(){
    if(isset($_POST["email"])){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        echo $wpdb->insert($wpdb->easymail_subscribers, array('email' => $email));
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_subscribers', 'subscribers');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribers', 'subscribers');
```

This is being call by AJAX request. I got this error message:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in **G:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\newsite\wp-content\themes\generic\functions.php** on line **235**

Tried really hard to solve this, but was not possible.

Comment: You have a "scope" problem. Look up "php variable scope". [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106497/21376) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using the global $wpdb

```
function subscribers(){
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST["email"])){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        echo $wpdb->insert($wpdb->easymail_subscribers, array('email' => $email));
    }
}
```